# advanced where clause fails

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get the records from a database where players have either played as player 1 or 2 in a game to calculate the gross profit for a player on a profile. I have the following Advanced Eloquent code:

```
 $user = User::with('profile')->where('name', $username)->first();

    $user_id = $user->id;
    $games_model = Games::where(function ($q) {
        global $user_id;
        $q->where('player1', '=', $user_id)->orWhere('player2', '=', $user_id);

    });


    $games = $games_model->limit(3)->get();
    // get gross profits

    $gross_profits = $games_model->sum('bet');

    dd($games_model->get()->toArray());
```

But when I try to take a look at the results dumped, I see a blank array. I am sure my user's ID is set correctly. The funny thing is it was only returning one result before instead of all the resulkts in the database. I'm confused. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Don't you need to return the query inside the where callback? Like `return $q->where(...)` Don't really remember.. BTW `$games = $games_model->sum('bet');` should not work, since `$games_model` is a query not a Collection. Maybe `$games->sum('bet');` would work.

Comment: Did you try to use some number for testing instead of `$user_id`?

Comment: that is not advance is you odd.... how are those relations?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, assuming the database and naming conventions are follow.

Users::class

```
public function games()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Games::class);
}
```

Query:

```
  Users::where('name', $username)
    ->has('games')
    ->with('profile')
    ->limit(3)
    ->get();
```

Haven't tested but this should give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

here's the solution.

`global` dosen't work every time depending on variable scope. I changed

```
 $games_model = Games::where(function ($q) {
        global $user_id;
        $q->where('player1', '=', $user_id)->orWhere('player2', '=', $user_id);

    });
```

to

```
 $user_id = $user->id;
    $games_model = Games::where(function ($q) use ($user_id) {
        $q->where('player1', '=', $user_id)->orWhere('player2', '=', $user_id);

    });
```

and it works perfectly every time.